# Prime factors of $2^{2^2}+3^{3^3}+5^{5^5}+7^{7^7}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, tetration

Are there any useful restrictions to the prime factors of the number

$$2^{2^2}+3^{3^3}+5^{5^5}+7^{7^7}?$$

The two smallest are $6771419$ and $72153167$, which I found by trial division. The number is small enough for ECM, but this is quite slow for numbers
of this magnitude.

Is there anything better than trial division or ECM ?

Comment: 'The number is small enough for ECM' - this number is roughly 700K decimal digits; AFAIK that's still well out of reach of even the best general-purpose factoring methods...

Comment: For people like me who like W|A... [it choked](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%202^2^2%20%2B%203^3^3%20%2B%205^5^5%20%2B%207^7^7&t=ff3tb01) on this.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the sum of the first two addends is prime.  Yet I entirely fail to see how that helps you in any way. `:)`